# How to build a neural network that infers a set of values for the most important feature?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, data-science

My task here is to find a way to get a suggested value of the most important feature or features. By changing into the suggested values of the features, I want the classification result to change as well.

[Snapshot of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyZn6.png)

The following is the procedures that I have tried so far:

1. Import dataset (shape: 1162 by 22)
2. Build a simple neural network (2 hidden layers)
3. Since the dependent variable is simply either 0 or 1 (classification problem), I onehot-encoded the variable. So it's either [0, 1] or [1,0]
4. After splitting into train & test data, I train my NN model and got accuracy of 77.8%
5. To know which feature (out of 21) is the most important one in the determination of either 0 or 1, I trained the data using Random Forest classifier (scikit-learn) and also got 77.8% accuracy and then used the 'feature_importances_' offered by the random forest classifier.
6. As a result, I found out that a feature named 'a_L4' ranks the highest in terms of relative feature importance.
7. The feature 'a_L4' is allowed to have a value from 0 to 360 since it means an angle. In the original dataset, 'a_L4' comprises of only 12 values that are [5, 50, 95, 120, 140, 160, 185, 230, 235, 275, 320, 345].
8. I augmented the original dataset by directly adding all the possible 12 values for each cases giving a new dataset of shape (1162x12 by 22).
9. I imported the augmented dataset and tested it on the previously trained NN model. The result was a FAILURE. There hardly was any change in the classification meaning almost no '1's switched to '0's.
10. My conclusion was that changing the values of 'a_L4' was not enough to bring a change in the classification. So I additionally did the same procedure again for the 2nd most important feature which in this case was 'b_L7_p1'.
11. So writing all the possible values that the two most important features can have, now the new dataset becomes the shape of (1162x12x6 by 22). 'b_L7_p1' is allowed to have 6 different values only, thus the multiplication by 6.
12. Again the result was a FAILURE.

So, my question is what might have I done wrong in the procedure described above? Do I need to keep searching for more important features and augment the data with all the possible values they can have? But since this is a tedious task with multiple procedures to be done manually and leads to a dataset with a huge size, I wish there was a way to construct an inference-based NN model that can directly give out the suggested values of a certain feature or features.

I am relatively new to this field of research, so could anyone please tell me some key words that I should search for? I cannot find any work or papers regarding this issue on Google.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: P.S. the possible values of all the features in the dataset do not follow a statistical model (e.g. Gaussian distribution), making it more difficult to infer a range of possible values the features can have

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for this kind of "postscripts" - edit & update your original post instead.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would approach the problem in the following way:

1. Normalize the whole dataset. As you can see from the dataset your features have different scales. It is utterly important that you make all features to have the same scale. Have a look at: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html
2. The second this that I would do now is train and evaluate a model (It can be whatever you want) to get a so called baseline model.
3. Then, I would try PCA to see whether all features are needed. Maybe you are including unnecessary sparsity to the model. See: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html
   For example if you set the `n_components` in PCA to be `0.99` then you are reducing the number of features while retaining as `0.99` explained variance.
4. Then I would train the model to see whether there is any improvement. Please note that only by adding the normalization itself there should be an improvement.
5. If I want to see by the dataset itself which features are important I would do: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest.html This would select a specified number of features based on some statistical test lets say: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html
6. Train a model and evaluate it again to see whether there is some improvement.

Also, you should be aware that the NNs can perform feature engineering by themselves, so computing feature importance is redundant in a way.

Let me know whether you will see any improvements.